# Profiling Performance of Complete Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, profiler

I want to profile CPU and memory utilisation of the complete Python Code written in a Jupyter Notebook. I have tried the existing profiler of Python, but found that it can profile only one function at a time. I want to profile the complete Notebook run that has numerous functions, more than 500 lines of code, which is split into various cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the way to do that with TensorBoard Profiler. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler.

Comment: Even found memory_profiler and line_profiler also useful.